# use / with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

this is my current .htaccess line for images:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).(ico|gif|jpg|png)$ /app/app/assets/images/$1.$2 [L]
```

But now it's not working for images that i put into subfolders (e.g. folder/image.png), does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:.+/)?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.(?:ico|gif|jpg|png))$ /app/app/assets/images/$1 [L]
```